# Android listview content refreshing

Tags: java, android, listview, parse-platform

I haver a list view in my android app that needs to be updated. Everything works fine, but the content is reloading every second time. For example if I reload the content once, the notifyDataSetChanged() is called, but nothing changes. On my second refresh, the data is reloaded. My third time same as first and so on.. What could be the problem? Here's my code:

```
private class LoadMoreDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> likeQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("Likes");
        likeQuery.whereEqualTo("username", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());
        likeQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            public void done(List<ParseObject> likeList, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    postList.clear();
                    try {
                        query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Images");
                        query.orderByDescending("createdAt");
                        query.setLimit(limit += 20);
                        ob = query.find();
                        for (ParseObject num : ob) {
                            PostRow test1;
                            Like singleLike = new Like(true);
                            for (int i = 0; i < likeList.size(); i++) {
                                if (likeList.get(i).get("imgId").equals(num.getObjectId())) {
                                    isLiked = true;
                                    break;
                                } else {
                                    isLiked = false;
                                }
                            }
                            singleLike.setLikeStatus(isLiked);
                            ParseFile img = (ParseFile) num.get("img");
                            test1 = new PostRow(img.getUrl().toString(), (String) num.get("username"), num.getObjectId(), singleLike, num.getInt("likeCount"));
                            postList.add(test1);
                        }
                    } catch (ParseException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    //error
                }
            }
        });
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        int position = listViewPosts.getFirstVisiblePosition();
        View v = listViewPosts.getChildAt(0);
        int top = (v == null) ? 0 : v.getTop();
        listViewPosts.setSelectionFromTop(position, top);
    }
}
```

Here's where I call the Async Task. It's an onrefresh listener, in another AsyncTask's onPostExecute method:

```
swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {

            new LoadMoreDataTask().execute();
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    });
```

Comment: post the code where you refresh using this asyntask

Comment: I've added the code in my post. It's an onrefresh listener, in another AsyncTask's onPostExecute method.

Comment: Looks like your starting a a background thread in your AsyncTask task, you need to either update the gui in the callback (Activity.runOnUiThread) or wait in the AsyncTask task for the background thread to finish. If you wait remember to use a simulationsly executing async task or you'll block your async task thread.

Comment: Yea, the problem was with the doinbackground method, probably it was still querying the database when I was calling the notifyDataSetChanged() method. Thank you.